# SAN Storage & Server for Oracle Replication

Tags: oracle, replication, storage

I need a 2-3 TB storage server group for Oracle Database.  We want SAN Storage & Server for Oracle Replication, but not Microsoft Storage Server.

For example : HP DL380 G6 as a server and EMC CLariion CX4 120 as a SAN Storage etc...

We have an option, but want some others.  What do you recommend for a Server & for SAN Storage (Make & Model) to use for Oracle Replication?

Comment: What OS? What Oracle licensing?

Comment: OS:Windows OS , Oracle Licencing: Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already got an EMC then [SRDF](http://uk.emc.com/products/detail/software/srdf.htm) is the obvious choice, tho' [Veritas Volume Replicator](http://www.symantec.com/business/volume-replicator) may be an option. SAN is not something you usually buy "off the shelf" the first time, the vendor will work with you to establish your requirements, both for performance and resilience. Other vendors you may which to consider are [HDS](http://www.hds.com/), [3Par](http://www.3par.com/index.html) and [NetApp](http://www.netapp.com/us/).

However my *recommendation* is to not use the storage for this, use [Data Guard](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/concepts.htm) because a) it's free once you already have paid for an oracle license and b) it enables [Active Standby](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/overview/active-data-guard-11g-datasheet-1-134534.pdf), something that I am very excited about myself.

Comment: Do you already use SAN?

Comment: No,I don't use already SAN.

Comment: I would advise calling a vendor for a chat then. You can pick the brains of one of their pre-sales engineers to help you clarify you requirements. I have some experience in this field, mainly with NetApp and HDS, and any of the vendors I linked to will be able to sort you out.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting.Firstly,I will planning all my requirements(cost,speed,mtbf etc.) then I will think.

Comment: @Cello until you talk to someone you won't know how all those requirements fit together, even tho you're going to be reading the numbers off a table. My advice is to seriously call a professional and LISTEN to what they have to say. Just like you came to this forum and asked these professionals what they had to say. I hope you LISTEN to them too.

Comment: @jcolebrand  thank you for your advice.I wanna just get a lot of idea related with Oracle Storage&Server.As you said , I will calling a professional.thanks again.